# Delete duplicate values but leaves the rows

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

Trying to crate a macro to clear ALL the duplicate values in a column but leaves the rows

This one works, but it leaves the first duplicate. I just want anything in that column duplicate to be cleared.

```
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With Sheets("Sheet1")
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
            For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
                If Application.CountIf(.Range("E1:E" & lastRow), .Range("E" & i)) > 1 Then
                .Range("E" & i).ClearContents
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Here is my original spreedsheet:

[image]

Here is what I need it to be:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way round this is to store all the cells to be cleared before clearing any, as this effects the COUNTIF, and do it all in one go at the end.

```
Sub x()

Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, r As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Application.CountIf(.Range("E1:E" & lastRow), .Range("E" & i)) > 1 Then
            If r Is Nothing Then
                Set r = .Range("E" & i)
            Else
                Set r = Union(r, .Range("E" & i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

If Not r Is Nothing Then r.ClearContents

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to use `Set r = IIf(r Is Nothing, .Range("E" & i), Union(r, .Range("E" & i)))` which I thought I had seen used elsewhere but got an invalid call error - if anyone has any thoughts, would be pleased to hear them.

Comment: Could do something slightly different, use a string to build up the range to delete, i.e. `strDel = strDel  & ",E" & i`, then at the end `Sheets("Sheet1").Range(right(strDel, len(strDel) - 1)).clearcontents` .

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a dictionary object to collect the cells that need to be cleared:

```
Option Explicit
'Set Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub deDup()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, rSrc As Range, C As Range
    Dim Dict As Dictionary, colRng As Collection
    Dim rDel As Range
    Dim v As Variant, w As Variant
    Dim sKey As String

'Set worksheet/range for the column to filter on
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet2")
With wsSrc
    Set rSrc = .Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp))
End With

Set Dict = New Dictionary
    Dict.CompareMode = TextCompare

For Each C In rSrc
    sKey = C.Value2
    If Not Dict.Exists(sKey) Then
        Set colRng = New Collection
        colRng.Add C
        Dict.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=colRng
    Else
        Dict(sKey).Add C
    End If
Next C

For Each v In Dict.Keys
    If Dict(v).Count > 1 Then
        For Each w In Dict(v)
            If rDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rDel = w
            Else
                Set rDel = Union(rDel, w)
            End If
        Next w
    End If
Next v

rDel.Clear

End Sub
```

If this runs too slowly because your data is very large, you can

- turn off `ScreenUpdating`, `Events` and set `Calculation` to `manual`
- or read the data into a VBA array and iterate through the data that way.